# Sandbox with roof, but it floods and sump doesn't do it

Tags: drainage, exterior

Built a roof covered sandbox for my kids, put a tarp at the bottom so groundwater wouldn't raise up, but the opposite problem keeps happening. My kids keep flooding it with water, and the and then becomes compact, hard, and also drains away. I have put the top of a 4L bucket (with 1" holes spaced about 5 inches apart) below the bottom of the sand, covered a sump pump with landscape fabric, filled the bucket with small rocks, covered the top of the sump with larger rocks, then some more landscape fabric, and then sand. Seems the groundwater problem is solved as when it rains, it no longer floods from groundwater, however, when my kids flood the sandbox, rather than the hose water having no effect on the sandbox, it fills up like a swimming pool and the sump fails to drain. Seems that the water is not making its way to the sump through the sand and landscape fabric. Anyone have any ideas on how to make a sandbox that will drain the water away so fast that the tykes cannot possibly flood it?

Thanks!

Comment: You cut a hole through the tarp under the sand and the hole is located over the sump pump basin and the water does not flow into your 4L basin?

Comment: your chance to teach your kids about consequences ... tell them that if they flood the sandbox, then they cannot use it until it drains

Comment: Sand filters in swimming pools work by allowing the water through without letting the sand , you need a fine enough mesh that will not plug up but still allow water flow it sounds like your landscape fabric may be two fine or multiple lay ears created a seal.

Comment: Definitely do **NOT** fix.  Until the kids learn that you aren't going to  repair everything they break, they'll keep on breaking it.   For that matter, why are you letting them anywhere near a water source?  There are far worse things they could think to flood.

Answer (score 0):

You may have two issues with water not draining out of the sandbox.
1. The sand is becoming compact and hard.  Use clean sand, purchased from a big box store in bags.  It seems your sand is mixed with other material that makes it solidify.  Sand from a rock place may be acceptable, but I have no idea how clean it is.
2. As Ed stated, you have too much filtering on top of your sump basin.  Your screen filter only needs at most two layers of screen door mesh.